# Creating class objects objective c

Tags: objective-c

I started transferring my java knowlege into objective c quite recently and got into making apps with xcode too. I do have a few things I'm confused about though. First of all in java when I'm making top down games and need to shoot a projectile, I would do that somewhat like:

```
public class Bullet{
    int x,y;
    public bullet(double x, double y){
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void tick(){
        //logic goes in here to move bullet
    }
}
```

then I'd have a class with an arraylist:

```
public class MainClass{
    ArrayList<Bullet> bulletlist;
    public main(){
        //create an arraylist that takes Bullet objects
        bulletlist = new ArrayList<Bullet>();
        //add a new bullet at the coordinate (100,100)
        bulletlist.add(new Bullet(100,100));



    }

    //gameloop(we'll pretend that this gets called every millisecond or so)
    public void gameloop(){
        //loop through list
        for(int i = 0; i < bulletlist.size(); i++){
            //run the method tick() at the current index
            bulletlist.get(i).tick();
        }
    }
}
```

so... my question is how would I translate this code into objective c. Or in other terms, how do I create an arraylist similar to the one in the example that creates an object of a class , then finally loop through this and call a loop method or whatever method I create inside.

Comment: Java and Objective-C are completely different languages with completely different object models.

Comment: actually I can transfer my knowledge... It's been going fine so far besides this. I got NSMutableArrays working but I was wondering how I can add an actual class to that array.

Comment: What do you mean by "add an actual class"? Objc doesn't have generics like Java and C++, you just add an object to it, like you would in java pre-1.5, when there were no generics.

Comment: -1 To learn how to create an array read Collections Programming Topics: [Arrays: Ordered Collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objective-C has no generics, unlike Java. It wouldn't make much sense, since Objective-C is dynamically typed (for the most part). Instead, `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray` store instances of `NSObject` or subtypes thereof (similar to `ArrayList<Object>` in Java).

---

Something like this should get you started.

```
@interface MainClass()

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *bullets;

@end

@implementation MainClass

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.bullets = [NSMutableArray array];
        [self.bullets addObject:[[Bullet alloc] initAtX:100 y:100]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)gameLoop {
    [self.bullets makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(tick)];
}

@end
```

Comment: I had to choose this as the best answer. Now I understand completely! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you create a new file inherited by `NSObject` with xcode, declare your header and your body, and your `ArrayList<Bullet>` can be a simple `NSMutableArray`. Your loop can look like this

```
NSMutableArray *bulletlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// fill the array

for(Bullet *bullet in bulletlist) // or a simple for loop
{
    [bullet tick];
}
```

for steps how to create and declera a class, just check some apple tutorials :)

Comment: All classes from the `Foundation` framework provide class (or `static`) constructors as well as those that act on objects.  Hence: `NSMutableArray *bulletlist = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this:

```
// bullet.h
@interface Bullet : NSObject

@property(assign, nonatomic) CGPoint position;
- (id)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)position;

@end

// bullet.m
@implementation Bullet

- (id)initWithPosition:(CGPoint)position {

    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _position = position;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then, in some other class that uses bullets (like a view controller), declare an array to keep the bullets...

```
#import "Bullet.h"

// put this in the class's interface
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *bullets;
```

... and add a new bullet like this:

```
[self.bullets addObject:[[Bullet alloc] initWithPosition:CGPointMake(100,100}];
```

... and iterate bullets like this:

```
for (Bullet *bullet in self.bullets) {
    NSLog(@"bullet position is %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(bullet.position));
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! I'm a little confused in how I should loop through the mutablearray though.

Comment: Edited to illustrate iteration anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your "main class" should be a UIViewController. It should create a UIView which is full screen on the phone. Then it adds a "CALayer" object as a sublayer of that view's layer.

There are various ways to draw into a CALayer, the best in this case would be to create a "BulletLayer" subclass of CALayer and do your drawing in that.

A view is a rectangle of the screen that the user can see and touch. A layer is a set of pixels stored in the video card's [very fast] memory that can be manipulated by your code. For best performance you will only draw the pixels once, and then move them around the screen (which can be done with animation, etc).

If you want specific answers about any particular part of that, you should ask a new question for each after checking if it's already answered somewhere.